# Any name for "focusing on the problem, not on the solution"

Tags: single-word-requests

Do we have a term to describe the attitude which instead of solution, focuses on the problem. This attitude is encouraged in many places and there are some stories about it. Maybe the most famous story is ["The Empty Soap Box"](http://swayamsat.org/blog.item.61/the-empty-soap-box.html).

I was thinking of **Pluralism** as a description for having many ways to get to one goal (not really relevant), or **lateral thinking** which is a superset of what I want.

What term is suitable?

Comment: *[Pluralism](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/pluralism)* means something else entirely.

Comment: just a comment on your question title: "focusing on the problem, not the solution" and "focusing on the target, not the path" actually sound like very different problems (generally, the solution *is* the target...)

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield thanks for your comment. I changed the title. Actually by target, I meant a physical target. For example, say that you want to go to country X (target). You have many paths to get there, many transportation options, many ways.

Answer (score 5):

[Thinking out of/outside the box](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_the_box)

> is a metaphor that means to think differently, unconventionally, or from a new perspective. This phrase often refers to novel or creative thinking. The term is thought to derive from management consultants in the 1970s and 1980s challenging their clients to solve the "nine dots" puzzle, whose solution requires some lateral thinking.

http://www.mycitysurat.com/images/article/puzzle_dotsnlines_ans.jpg

References

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box)
- [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/out_of_the_box)
- [The free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out-of-the-box+thinking)

---

Previous answer, kept for relevance

When I first read the question I believed you were referring to the [XY-problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) which is referred at [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

> The X-Y Problem, as it is sometimes called, is a mental block which leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and energy, both on the part of people asking for help, and on the part of those providing help. It often goes something like this:
>
> - User wants to do X.
> - User doesn't know how to do X, but thinks they can fumble their way to a solution if they can just manage to do Y.
> - User doesn't know how to do Y either.
> - User asks for help with Y.
> - Others try to help user with Y, but are confused because Y seems like a strange problem to want to solve.
>
> After much interaction and wasted time, it finally becomes clear that the user really wants help with X, and that Y wasn't even a suitable solution for X.

Comment: Nice term. But it's not well recognized. I'm searching for a more formal, widely recognized term, such that can be found in credible sites like Wikipedia. Thanks for answering though. +1.

Comment: Thinking outside the box is very recognised!

Comment: But perhaps isn't specific enough - the questioner didn't necessarily need this degree of creativity ("*lateral thinking* is a superset...").

Comment: ouside the box is an often used synonym for Lateral thinking

Comment: Does not seem to be a single word, as the OP requests.

Answer (score 1):

There are many interpretations of this.

- A management consultant might like *Goal-oriented* (*-directed*, *-driven* etc.).
- The second solution in your story was, in the *engineering* sense *elegant*.
- How about [*enterprising*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enterprising): 2. characterized by great imagination or initiative
- Or even [*resourceful*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/resourceful): able to deal skillfully and promptly with new situations, difficulties, etc.

In contrast simply "focusing on the problem" (or at least dwelling on the negative aspects of it) could be construed as *pessimistic*.

Comment: Not really informative and descriptive :)

Comment: @mplungjan I wouldn't have proposed it on its own, but included it as an example of several takes on the question.  From [M-W:pessimism](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pessimism) "1 :  *an inclination to emphasize adverse aspects, conditions*, and possibilities or to expect the worst possible outcome" Sounds like focussing on the problem to me.

Comment: @mplungjan, it was in contrast to my rather more positive examples.  I'll tweak my answer to downgrade that example and comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are various phrases using the term *[big picture](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big%20picture)*

> the entire perspective on a situation or issue —used with *the*

Two common phrases are

> *seeing the big picture*
>
> *big picture thinking*

There are numerous articles and books discussing the differences between people who tend to be *big picture* thinkers as opposed to *detail oriented* thinkers, such as this [essay](http://www.psychologies.co.uk/self/thinking-big-in-a-details-world.html).

Comment: Yeah, big picture denotes that concept to some extent. But it's more like a description of a thing, rather than an attitude.

Answer (score 0):

In the UK, we'd call this 'belt and braces' or 'check the basics'. No point in taking the computer apart to find out why it's not working if you haven't checked the power supply is functioning, or that the fuse hasn't blown in the plug - that's called a belt and braces approach. Not one word though, obviously...

UPDATE: mplungian: not so. 'Belts and braces' also refers to looking at a whole problem, with an overview, or a birds' eye view if you like, singling out the possible issues, and then deciding, by prioritising the identified possible causes, how best to resolve the situation. For interest's sake, in the Empty Box story, the reaction of the company to try to solve the issue would, in London colloquial terminology, be called half cocked (meaning off and running before looking properly, or only half ready).

Comment: Belt and braces does not relate to thinking laterally. It refers to making redundantly sure something works

Comment: I do not agree. I have only ever seen _using more than one method to make sure that something is safe or sure to happen_ and dictionaries back me up. If the fan guy additionally had a person poke boxes that budged when blown at in case they had stuck to the belt, then it was belt and braces

Comment: Well, that's okay, I don't have a problem if you have a different opinion from mine.